# Product of "Non-Cauchy" and Cauchy Sequencs: Always Cauchy, Always "Non-Cauchy", Sometimes Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Is there an intuitive argument to this? I know that the product of 2 Cauchy sequences is Cauchy, but that doesn't necessarily mean that all Cauchy sequences involve the product of 2 individual Cauchy sequences, does it?

I thought of the following:

The product of a "Non-Cauchy" sequence and a Cauchy sequence is always "Non-Cauchy" because successive terms would never get arbitrarily close to one another as their index increases, marked by the product of the divergent term. Is this logic bad?

Comment: What about the Cauchy one being the all-zero one, for instance?

Comment: By product of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ do you mean $(a_nb_n)$ or something else, like the Cauchy product? If $(a_nb_n)$, the product of a non-Cauchy and a Cauchy can easily be Cauchy, use $a_n=n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, can we generalize this? What if Cauchy one isn't all zero, or 1/n and n? These are optimal cases that generate an all singular set like all 0's and 1's.

Comment: These examples were given because are quick and easy to see, but it doesn't take much to generalize them. Instead of $1\over n$, let $b_n = {c_n\over n}$ where $c_n$ is any convergent sequence.